# How to stop the timer from looping when it comes to 0:00?

Tags: javascript

When it comes the end it keeps looping back. How do I stop it to and how to create and alert saying Game ended?

```
if(levelOption === 0) {
    time = 60 * 0.1, g = document.getElementById('g'), tmp = time;
    setInterval(function() {
        var c = tmp--, m = (c/60) >> 0, s = (c-m*60) + '';
        g.textContent = '' + m + ':' + (s.length > 1 ? '' : '0') + s tmp != 0 || (tmp = time); 
    }, 1000);
} else if(levelOption === 1) {
    time = 60 * 10, g = document.getElementById('g'), tmp = time;
    setInterval(function(){
        var c = tmp--, m = (c/60) >> 0, s = (c-m * 60) + '';
        g.textContent = '' + m + ':' + (s.length > 1 ? '' : '0') + s tmp != 0 || (tmp = time); 
    }, 1000);
} else {
    time = 60 * 20, g = document.getElementById('g'), tmp = time;
    setInterval(function() {
        var c = tmp--, m = (c/60) >> 0, s = (c-m * 60) + '';
        g.textContent = '' + m + ':' + (s.length > 1 ? '' : '0') + s tmp != 0 || (tmp = time); 
    }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you first name your interval by saving it to a variable (`var myCounter = setInterval(...)`) you can later clear the interval using `clearInterval(myCounter)`.

I don't know in which context you are using these counters but i think you can simplify the logic. See if this counter works for you:

```js
time = 3,
g = document.getElementById('g'),
tmp = time;

// Here we name our interval
var myCounter = setInterval(function() {

  // Clear the interval if our counter has reached 0
  if(tmp == 0) clearInterval(myCounter)

  // Set minute and second values
  var m = (tmp / 60) >> 0,
      s = tmp - m * 60;

  // Print values
  g.textContent = m + ':' + ((s>9)?'':'0') + s;

  // Finish of with modifying the counter
  tmp--;
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="g"></div>
```

Comment: How would I change the time to 5 minutes instead of 3 seconds?

Comment: `time` is in seconds. 60 seconds in one minute gives `time = 60 * 5` for 5 minutes. And I updated the way the snippet prints the `s` value!

Comment: Yes that would make sense. Thank you.

Comment: I tried to update the `s` value by `r.textContent = m + ':' + ((s.length>1)?'':' ') + s;` but the 5 minutes drops the 0 e.g. 5:0, and the it goes back to 4:59. How would you get it to go 5:00?

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly it's because in your original code, `s` is a string, and you can test for `s.length` without problems. In my updated snippet `s` is an integer, which means `s.length` will not work. With an integer the easier way to test if it's a 1 or 2 digit number is to check its actual value (9 is the highest 1 digit number).

Comment: Thank you, I understand.

Answer (score 0):

1. Save setInterval value to some variable, e.g. `let interval = setInterval;`
2. In interval function if time is <= 0 do a [clearInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp) like `clearInterval(interval);`